How to iterate over variables list in Gitlab pipeline?
I'm trying to deploy my Docker image and I would like to create .env file with all environment variables. Is there some way to iterate over all pipeline variables?
.gitlab-ci.yaml:
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './secure_files'
  PROJECT_NAME: magicfeedback/django
  ...
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    for variable in ${variables}
    do
      echo "$variable" >> .env
      echo "export $variable" >> .env_export
    done


You can put all your variables using env command
env > .env
env | sed  's/\(.*\)/export \1/' > .env

You would have to much variables though. So if you want to filter it a bit, you can make your variable start with MYCI
env | grep MYCI > .env
env | grep MYCI | sed  's/\(.*\)/export \1/' > .env


The problem is how to access to variables list in yaml file definition an iterate like: job:   script:     - |       for variable in variables       do          echo "$variable" >> .env         echo "export $variable" >> .env_export       done
